# Transfering a Laravel 5 app to live server

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel, laravel-5

I uploaded my laravel 5 site from my localhost to a live server.
I added an `.htaccess` file to the `public` folder and added the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

I know most places explain to change the public folder but I couldn't for the life of me get that to work.

Now everything works except everything in `/public/` folder.
(wouldn't the `.htaccess` I added fix that?)

Anyway, could someone please help me add some sort of redirect rule or anything else that will get my public folder to work?
Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

My mistake.
One of the css files didn't transfer correctly.
For anyone that sees this thread, the above solution works.